# How to convert this format hexadecimal?

Tags: python, hex

I need to convert the format of this number:

```
CB0D8A83 7FBC1D22 86388A2D AFA0B9A1
```

I read this number:

```
ciphertext= (ser.read(45))
print(ciphertext)
Ciphertxt_file.write(ciphertext)
```

to this format:

```
cb0d8a837fbc1d2286388a2dafa0b9a1
```

I would be very grateful if yo could help me.

Comment: So you want to put them in lowercase?

Comment: `input.replace(' ', '').lower()` would do that. It's not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: yes please @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: You don't have a 'binary format' as far as I can determine. You just have a lowercased hex string with no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert them to lowercase with `.lower()` and remove the whitespace with `.replace(' ','')`:

```
result = ciphertext.lower().replace(' ','')
```

No need to use advanced tools here. This is however **not** a binary format (the binary format uses zeros and ones like `00110101101110`). Furthermore this method does not check the format so `1134ZZ223` would be accepted as well.

Comment: It  gives me this error: NameError: name 'hexstr' is not defined

Comment: @tssmokey46: well of course you first need a string called `hexstr`. What is the name of the variable that currently holds you unformatted string?

Comment: I edit my publication to make it clear: than: this  what I put according to your answer: ciphertext_16b=hexstr.lower(ciphertext).replace(' ','')

Comment: @tssmokey46: in that case you should simply call with `ciphertext`. Updated answer.